# Tikz node does not appear in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I have a command for putting a text in a rounded corner box with bg-color.
It uses tikz node:

```
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt]{#1};}
```

When I use this box inside a forest node, the node doesn't appear.
Please could you tell me the reason?
and how to achieve the same effect in forest and still having nice formatting options like tikz?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\tikz[overlay]\node[fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt]{#1};}

\begin{document}

\tikz\node[fill=blue!20,rectangle, rounded corners=2pt]{123}; 

\mybox{inside box}

\begin{forest}
for tree={align=center, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, l sep=5mm}
[\tikz\node{eee}; node1  
 [\mybox{2} node2
  [\mybox{3} node3]
  [\mybox{4} node4]
 ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you want? a label like `123` beside every tree node? or every tree node like label `123`?

Comment: a label with a bg-color inside a node: `\node{\mybox{label} text};`

Comment: Note that nesting `tikzpicture`s is generally dodgy. It will work in simple cases, but more often fail in more complex ones. That's the problem here, I think. You are nesting `tikzpicture`s without controlling, for example, when things are expanded and so on, and that is not going to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by [AboAmmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292439/), the trick here is to use **forest**'s keys to get the result you want.

For convenience, we can define a TikZ style and a corresponding **forest** one.

```
\tikzset{
  my blue box/.style={fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt},
}
\forestset{
  my blue label/.style={
    label={[my blue box]left:#1},
    s sep+=10pt,
  }
}
```

As [AboAmmar shows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292439/), the TikZ style can be passed in `for tree` if the settings should simply apply to every node of the tree as such.

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    my blue box,
  }
  [eee node1
    [2 node2
     [3 node3]
     [4 node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: styled nodes]

Or you can use the **forest** style to easily specify the contents of labels to be created to the left of specific nodes in the tree.

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
  }
  [node1, my blue label=eee
    [node2, my blue label=2
     [node3, my blue label=3]
     [node4, my blue label=4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: specific labels]

In some cases, the labels can also be added automatically based on information about the node's location etc. in the tree. For example, based on the node's level or placement relative to its siblings or, in this case, on the node's internal `id`.

This default label can then be overridden for specific nodes using the `my blue label` style used earlier.

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    label/.wrap pgfmath arg={% specify default label for nodes
      {[my blue box]left:#1}
    }{int(id()-1)},
    s sep+=10pt,
  }
  [node1, my blue label=eee% override default label for this node
    [node2
     [node3]
     [node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: auto-labelling with optional override]

Another, similar option is to add the labels using TikZ code after the tree is drawn. We can add a couple more **forest** styles to facilitate this.

```
\forestset{
  ...
  my blue postscript/.style={
    tikz={\node [my blue box, anchor=east] at (.west) {#1};},
    s sep+=10pt,
  },
  auto blue postscripts/.style={
    my blue postscript/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{int(id()-1)},
  }
}
```

Then `auto blue postscripts` will add the label or labels automatically, as before, and `my blue postscript=<content>` will add a specific label, if automated labelling isn't activated or if the automatic label should be overridden in a particular case.

Then

```
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    auto blue postscripts,
  }
  [node1, my blue postscript=eee
    [node2
     [node3]
     [node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: automated labelling with override option using TikZ code directly]

However, there is no real advantage to this more complex option in this case that I can see, so I'd recommend the method relying on `label` above.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt, multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  my blue box/.style={fill=blue!20, rectangle, rounded corners=2pt},
}
\forestset{
  my blue label/.style={
    label={[my blue box]left:#1},
    s sep+=10pt,
  },
  my blue postscript/.style={
    tikz={\node [my blue box, anchor=east] at (.west) {#1};},
    s sep+=10pt,
  },
  auto blue postscripts/.style={
    my blue postscript/.wrap pgfmath arg={##1}{int(id()-1)},
  }
}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    my blue box,
  }
  [eee node1
    [2 node2
     [3 node3]
     [4 node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
  }
  [node1, my blue label=eee
    [node2, my blue label=2
     [node3, my blue label=3]
     [node4, my blue label=4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    label/.wrap pgfmath arg={
      {[my blue box]left:#1}
    }{int(id()-1)},
    s sep+=10pt,
  }
  [node1, my blue label=eee
    [node2
     [node3]
     [node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    align=center,
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    l sep=5mm,
    auto blue postscripts,
  }
  [node1, my blue postscript=eee
    [node2
     [node3]
     [node4]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. Previously I was putting labels in the content of a node, but since there is special syntax for labeling I will stick to that.

Comment: It will be easier, I think, even if it takes getting used to. Just remember to increase `s sep` a bit to make room for the labels.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to your tree options the following: `rounded corners=2pt, fill=blue!20` and there is no need for the `\mybox{}` command you've created.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={align=center, parent anchor=south, child anchor=north, l sep=5mm, rounded corners=2pt, fill=blue!20}
[node1  
 [ node2
  [ node3]
  [ node4]
 ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I want to get in the end.
A node should contain a text in box and a text without box.
See the mwe: `[\mybox{2} node2`

Comment: The `\tikz\node{eee}; ` in the root node is spurious. (Unsurprisingly, it has no effect; surprisingly, it doesn't produce an error.) Hope you don't mind: I edited so I could vote this up without checking back first. (Laziness....)